# jQuery - performance of element detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm reading code of my collegues and I'm wondering if the performance could be improved.
For any button-event there is code like that:

a)

```
$("body").on("click", ".aButtonName", function() { ....});
$("body").on("click", ".aButtonName", function() { ....});
$("body").on("click", ".aButtonName", function() { ....});

....
$("body").on("click", ".aButtonName", function() { ....});
```

b) Would it be faster to analyse each target-event, after the body is clicked:

```
  $(document.body).on('click', function( e ){

var trg = $(e.target).closest('button');
if(!trg || !trg.attr('class'))
  return;


if ( trg.attr('class').indexOf('my_button') > -1) {
  ....
```

Comment: no.... because in this case in any click on the body the selector has to be evaluated.... instead you need to target the least common element to bind the handler in case of event delegation

Comment: This would improve performance in case functions are handling more buttons, otherwise it's just the same as if the event was attached directly to the element..

Comment: Using `$(document.body)` instead of `$("body")` would give a slight improvement. Better yet, save body to a var `var $body = $(document.body);`.

Comment: building up on @user13500 why not something like http://jsfiddle.net/5nRn7/1/

Comment: @user2952265 DOM queries are expensive, you should always do as few as possible. But that's in general, it doesn't relate specifically to events.

Comment: This question could possibly be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It would most likely reduce performance. In the second scenario, you end up executing the callback function, passing parameters, and performing several DOM interactions just to exit. In the first, jQuery performs a selector match and only executes the function if there is a match.

In both styles, the event is handled once it "bubbles up" (propagates) to the `body`. This "delegate-style" checks to see if the selector matches the target (or a parent).

As others suggest, caching the `$("body")` would save a number of DOM queries and you could get better performance by using a closer/smaller delegate than `body`.

Comment: Thank You very much, could you mark your explanation with a) and b). I 'm getting confused to which you are referring and what is a better solution.

Comment: @user2952265: You’re not able to map “first” and “second” to “a)” and “b)” yourself …?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear. If you want to raise an event whenever we click on body Simply u can follow the below code.

```
<body>
   <ul>
      ......
   </ul>
  </body>
```

In js file

```
  $('body').click(function(event){
   $(this).find('ul').addClass('selected');

    });
```